# Display array in Alphabetically order Using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, alphabetical

I want to display student list according to their result in Alphabetically ascending order. Suppose, Students name who are obtained A grade display first, then who obtained B. I have tried but it is not showing in Alphabetic order.

Thanks for any help.

```
My code
controller:

function showResult(){

         $data['count']=$this->data_Model->getStudent('result');


        $this->load->view('section',$data); 

      } 
Model:
    public function getStudent($table) {


      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $table order by grade asc");

          return $query->result_array();

    }

View

section.php
            <?php 
               foreach($count as $student):

                  echo $student['name']; 
                  echo $student['grade'];
              endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: You can use the native php function `sort` using the `SORT_STRING` flag. http://php.net/manual/de/function.sort.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply list the "order by" fields by priority. Ascending is the default so you don't have to specify that.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $table order by grade, name");
```